# Orchard CMS Logging data store in database?

Tags: database, logging, orchardcms, store

I want to store all my loggign exception data in the database. I can log them in file, but with db , added appender attribute in log4net.config , but no success. Can anybody share some advise ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far, specifically the code that isn't working.

Comment: Thnaks @Stephen Newell. first of all, I am quite new in Orchard cms. i ran the db script and add the config which I got in http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html. Instantiate the Logger in constructor of AdminController. Assign logger.error in one method where en error exception arise. is that the right way to store or I have to go through like the normal way Orchard stores in db ?

Comment: I  solved it.. the problem was in config file.

Comment: @user3445970 ...then please post an answer describing in detail how you solved it. Nobody can make use of a generic "it was the config file".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html has provided almost all databases sample config file to store the logging data  into the database table. Run scripts for creating the table and add the config file in the project. Be cautious all the parameter name and layout spelling.

I tested for MS SQL, worked for me and will works for any other databse too.

Happy coding